# Spring integration multiple tcp connections to different servers

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

Is it possible to set up a dynamic TCP client that can connect to multiple TCP servers at once?
I'm using spring integration with dsl configuration. I've read some other questions about this topic but can't figure out a way to make it work.

The configuration I use to set up a single connection below:

```
@Configuration
public class TcpAsyncConfig {

MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler();

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory client1() {
    return Tcp.netClient("localhost", 6050)
            .leaveOpen(true)
            .soKeepAlive(true)
            .singleUseConnections(true)
            .deserializer(new CustomSerializerDeserializer())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow client1Out(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client1) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(RobotGateways.class)
            .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(client1))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow client1In(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client1) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(client1))
            .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
            .log(msg -> "client1: " + msg.getPayload())
            .handle(handler::handleMessage)
            .get();
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("client1Out")
public RobotGateways robotGateways(RobotGateways gateways){
    return gateways;
}
}
```

So I want to create a list of connections and use the gateway to send messages on a specific connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` can really connect only to one TCP server. To make connections to different server you need to have several `Tcp.netClient()`, respectively.

You then probably need to have several `Tcp.outboundAdapter()` and `Tcp.inboundAdapter()` definitions.

In the gateway flow, to determine to which client to send, you need to take a look into a `route()` where according some gateway call argument you can decide to where to go in your flow.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

Comment: See this sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client for an example of registering dynamic DSL flows for TCP Clients and routing to them.